# Sdk xamarin blank map loading app from background

Tags: ios, google-maps, xamarin

We've been using the latest version (unified API) of the iOS Google Maps component from xamarin in our app with great success. We of course have the proper API key in place and can render maps all day with custom markers and other features.

Our problem is that when the app "sometimes" comes back from being in the background (home button pressed), the map no longer draws any data on it. The map is blank but the Google logo is still in the bottom left corner so I know the control hasn't been unloaded. Once in this blank map state we have to kill the app and restart it to start getting map data drawn again. There are no exceptions thrown and no errors in the iOS logs. I have done a lot of research and this issue also presents it self when the maps do not have a proper API key but that clearly isn't our scenario unless somehow the maps component is losing that API key connection?

what could be the cause of this and how can we fix it Please? can we pay for support from xamarin for this issue if there is no 'quick fix'?

Here is the screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Comment: I do not see any of your screenshot of issue.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/tv0rue6iv/

Comment: This issue is related to `xamarin` and you can ask [here](http://xamarin.com/support) for a support of fix.

Comment: Thanks.  We already posted on xamarin forums.  No luck so far.  Was hoping someone else out there has found a work around or fix for this.

Comment: This issue also occurs with the native iOS SDK, see the bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7782  Please update if you've found a solution

Answer (score 0):

No worry I also had the same problem when I'm working with this Component
try not to save API Key on any constants. Directly pass the value. If it is not working try regenerating the API Key. Map should
 I thing currently you are following this code pattern like how they provide

```
using Google.Maps;
...

[Register ("AppDelegate")]

public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    const string MapsApiKey = "<Get your ID at https://code.google.com/apis/console/>";


public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    MapServices.ProvideAPIKey (MapsApiKey);
    ...
}
}
```

Instead of this code you can directly pass the API Key like below or you might be forgot to remove the angle brackets.

```
MapServices.ProvideAPIKey ("AIzaSyAnxfhuAwEqdVhQpoUkGFZpsBukOSXVFr0");
```

Happy coding:)